# firebird sql order by

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

i got a dataset which looks like this:

```
customernumber year value

1    2011   500
2    2011   100
1    2010   400
3    2010   600
3    2011   300
2    2010   700
```

i want it to be ordered by highest value of year 2011, but the rows of each customer need to stay together.

it should look like this:

```
customernumber year value

1    2011   500
1    2010   400
3    2011   300
3    2010   600
2    2011   100
2    2010   700
```

is this even possible?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` to bring that value in, and then you can use it for the `oder by`:

```
select d.customernumber, d.year, d.value
from dataset d join
     (select d.*
      from dataset d
      where d.year = 2011
     ) d2011
     on d.customernumber = d2011.customernumber
order by d2011.value, d.customernumber, d.year desc;
```

In databases that support window functions, this can more easily be done as:

```
select d.*
from dataset d
order by max(case when year = 2011 then value end) over (partition by customernumber),
         customernumber, year desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  customernumber, year, value from mytable  
group by customernumber, year, value 
order by year desc
```

Comment: with this sql i only get 1 column per customernumber

Comment: Are you sure?  Did you try it?  You will get only one record if all year and value are the same for 2 different entries

Comment: The `group by` is useless if you use `distinct` (or vice versa). One of them is enough